# Reveal div by clicking a link, make it hidden again by clicking another

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to html and css, so this may be a stupid question, but I want an area where there is a text you can click on that reveals an entire div full of text, with another clickable text at the bottom to hide it again, completely JQuery and Javascript free, only using html and css. Not only that but I need several of them one on top of the other. This is what I've got so far:

```css
.horizontal-box{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.displayable-text{
  display: none;
}
#one.show:target ~ #one.displayable-text{
  display: inline-block;
}
#one.hide:target ~ #one.displayable-text{
  display: none;
}
#two.show:target ~ #two.displayable-text{
  display: inline-block;
}
#two.hide:target ~ #two.displayable-text{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-box">
  <div>
    Bla bla bla
    <a href="#one" class="show">show text</a>
    <div id="one" class="displayable-text">
      Bla bla bla
      <a href="#one" class="hide">hide text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  Bla bla bla
    <a href="#two" class="show">show text</a>
    <div id="two" class="displayable-text">
      Bla bla bla
      <a href="#two" class="hide">hide text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could someone please explain to me what I've done wrong or tell me how to do it? I have no idea of why it doesn't work.

Comment: I wanted the `.hide` element to appear and disappear with the `.displayable-text`

Comment: I found out today that you can do almost entirely the same with the `<details>` and `<summary>` tags, although it allows for extraordinarily little customization. The code would look like this:
`<details>
<summary>Text to always be shown</summary>
Text to be shown only after clicking on an icon
</details>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only way I can think of without using JS. I'm using the labels `for` attribute to target a hidden checkbox's `ID`. In the CSS I'm using the `input:checked` selector to hide and show the div with the hidden content.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.pointer {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.horizontal-box {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.displayable-text {
  display: none;
}
input:checked ~ div {
  display: inline-block;
}
input:checked ~ label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-box">
  <div>
    Bla bla bla
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" class="hidden">
    <label for="one" class="pointer"><strong>show text</strong></label>
    <div class="hidden">
      Bla bla bla
      <label for="one" class="pointer"><strong>hide text</strong></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Bla bla bla
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" class="hidden">
    <label for="two" class="pointer"><strong>show text</strong></label>
    <div class="hidden">
      Bla bla bla
      <label for="two" class="pointer"><strong>hide text</strong></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#one` only targets elements with `id="one"` not `href="#one"`.
`#one.show` and `#one.hide` makes no sense as show/hide buttons don't have an id. And the id needs to be unique, so you can't have them on multiple elements.

And usage of [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) also makes no sense as `.hide` and `.displayable-text` are child and parent and not siblings.

---

The solution is a lot more simple.

There is no need to write CSS with selector targeting specific ids.

Just show elements that are targeted and make the hide button clear the target.

```css
.horizontal-box{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.displayable-text{
  display: none;
}
.displayable-text:target {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-box">
  <div>
    Bla bla bla One
    <a href="#one" class="show">show text</a>
    <div id="one" class="displayable-text">
      More Bla bla bla One
      <a href="#" class="hide">hide text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Bla bla bla Two
    <a href="#two" class="show">show text</a>
    <div id="two" class="displayable-text">
      More Bla bla bla Two
      <a href="#" class="hide">hide text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** With `:target` you can only have one `div` open, since you can only have one target at a time.